# Check if there are nspopover opened before creating new one

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nspopover

I have in my code some functionality to open a popover anytime an event happens. Problem is that if those events happen one after the other the popovers opened are overlapped.

I would like to close one popover when opening new one.

Is there any way to get from nswindow if there is an active popover?

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you need play with NSPopover's notification methods such as:

```
- (void)popoverDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)popoverWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

And add some logic which will hide not closed popover...

Comment: But how do I find the not closed popover?

Comment: For example you can store previous opened popover in the property.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to figure it out by using notifications posted:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(popoverWillShow:)
           name:NSPopoverWillShowNotification
         object:nil];
```

And then in the selector I compare the objects: (popover is an NSPopover)

```
- (void)popoverWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if (![popover isEqual:[notification object]])
  [self close];
}
```